# ServiceStack AutoQuery get random rows

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I am migrating from EF6 and trying ServiceStack AutoQuery and I came to a bump - cant find a way to get random rows from database.

Also is there a way to create computed columns directly in ORMLite POCO so i can manipulate some data for example create FULL NAME from FIRST NAME and LAST NAME.

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The least non-invasive way of returning additional "computed" info to your Services without adding them to a DB Table is to create a getter property annotated with `[Ignore]` where it will be ignored by OrmLite but still serialized when returned from a Service, e.g:

```
public class Contact
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }
 
    [Ignore]
    public string FullName => FirstName + " " + LastName;
}

[Route("/contacts")]
public class QueryContacts : QueryDb<Contact> {}
```

An alternative for returning "computed" data in OrmLite queries is to use OrmLite's [[CustomSelect] attribute](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#customselect-attribute) to have OrmLite return a computed SQL Expression instead of a column, e.g:

```
public class Contact
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }
 
    [CustomSelect("FirstName || ' ' || LastName")]
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

From **v5.9.1** that's now [available on MyGet](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget) you can Order By "Random" to order by random rows, e.g:

```
/contacts?OrderBy=Random
```

Where it will order by the selected RDBMS `RANDOM()` function to return rows in  a random order.

Prior versions of ServiceStack can also achieve it using `[CustomSelect]` by returning a column using the RDBMS RANDOM() function (typically RAND() or RANDOM()), e.g:

```
public class Contact
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }
 
    [CustomSelect("FirstName || ' ' || LastName")]
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    [CustomSelect("RAND()")]
    public int Random { get; set; }
}
```

Where you can [order it like any other column](https://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery-rdbms#paging-and-ordering), e.g:

```
/contacts?OrderBy=Random
```

The `[IgnoreDataMember]` attribute will ignore the property in text serializers and prevent it from being serialized.

Alternatively you can have the Service always return queries in random order (unless a specific Order is specified) with a [Custom AutoQuery implementation](https://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery-rdbms#custom-autoquery-implementations), e.g:

```
public class MyServices : Service
{
    public IAutoQueryDb AutoQuery { get; set; }
    
    public async Task<object> Any(QueryContacts query)
    {
        using var db = AutoQuery.GetDb(query, base.Request);
        var q = AutoQuery.CreateQuery(query, base.Request, db);
        if (query.OrderBy == null) 
            q.OrderByRandom();
        return await AutoQuery.ExecuteAsync(query, q, base.Request, db);        
    }
}
```

Comment: Id didnt work :( so I ended with [CustomSelect("NewID()")]
        public string RandiID { get; set; }

Comment: @exe.bat then you must be using SQL Server which is different to the rest. In latest v5.9.1 on MyGet you can now `?OrderBy=Random` to return results in a random order where it will use the appropriate RANDOM() function for your RDBMS. As you already have v5.9.1 installed you'll need to [clear your NuGet packages cache](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget#redownloading-myget-packages).